# How to fill in the columns of R dataframe with the corresponding column names as values

Tags: r, for-loop

I have the following dataframe in R

```
  DF_1<-data.frame("SL:NO"= c(1:3))
  DF_1$A<-NA
  DF_1$B<-NA

     SL.NO   A  B
      1      NA NA
      2      NA NA
      3      NA NA
```

How do i fill the columns that are empty so that columns A, and B are filled with A, B . the result should be

```
  Sl.NO A B
    1   A B
    2   A B
    3   A B
```

I have used a nested for loop as follows.

```
 for( i in namelist){
  for(j in 1:nrow(DF_1)){
  DF_1[j,i]=i }}
```

Is there a simpler more elegant way to do the same

Answer (score 3):

We can use `Map` to replace `NA` values in each column

```
DF_1[] <- Map(function(x, y) replace(x, is.na(x), y), DF_1, names(DF_1))

DF_1
#  SL.NO A B
#1     1 A B
#2     2 A B
#3     3 A B
```

Comment: This works. Thank you. One small query. What do the square braces after DF_1 imply

Comment: @Raghavanvmvs `Map` returns a list. The `[]` ensures that the output maintains the same structure as the original `DF_1`.